# EF6 Disable Query Plan Caching with Command Tree Interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

I'm using `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` to implement soft-delete functionality. Inside standard `TreeCreated` method I check whether given query command contains models with soft-delete attribute. If they do and user requested to fetch soft deleted object too --- I call my soft-delete visitor with `querySoftDeleted` = `true`. This will make my query return all object, those with `true` and those with `false` values on `IsDeleted` property.

```
public class SoftDeleteInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor {
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext) {
        ...            

        bool shouldFetchSoftDeleted = context != null && context.ShouldFetchSoftDeleted;

        this.visitor = new SoftDeleteQueryVisitor(ignoredTypes, shouldFetchSoftDeleted);

        var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(this.visitor);

        ...
    }
}


public class SoftDeleteQueryVisitor {

    ...

    public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
    {
        // Skip filter if all soft deleted items should be fetched
        if (this.shouldFetchSoftDeleted)
            return base.Visit(expression);

        ...
        // TODO Apply `IsDeleted` filter.
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to retrieve all objects (soft-deleted too) and then with the same query later object that are not deleted only. Something like this:

```
context.ShouldFetchSoftDeleted = true;
var retrievedObj= context.Objects.Find(obj.Id);
```

And then in new instance of context (not in same context)

```
var retrievedObj= context.Objects.Find(obj.Id);
```

Second time, `ShouldFetchSoftDeleted` is set to false, everything is great, but EF decides that this query was same as one before and retrieves it from cache. Retrieved query does not contain filter and thus returns all objects (soft-deleted and not). Cache is not cleared when context is disposed.

Now the question is whether there is a way, ideally, to mark constructed `DbCommand` so that it does not get cached. Can this be done? Or is there a way to force query recompilation?

There are ways to avoid caching, but I would rather not have to change every query in application just to fix this.

More info on Query Plan Caching can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3).

**Edit 1**

I'm using new context for each request - object caching should not be the problem.

**Edit 2**

Here is database log. First call is with soft-delete and second is w/o. `...` parts are identical so I excluded them from log. You can see that both requests are identical. First one calls `CreateTree` and resulted tree is cached so that when you execute, tree is retrieved from cache and my soft-delete flag is not re-applied when it should be.

```
Opened connection at 16.5.2015. 2:34:25 +02:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0


-- p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int64, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 16.5.2015. 2:34:25 +02:00

-- Completed in 22 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 16.5.2015. 2:34:25 +02:00

The thread 0x1008 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1204 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xf94 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Opened connection at 16.5.2015. 2:34:32 +02:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0


-- p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int64, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 16.5.2015. 2:34:32 +02:00

-- Completed in 16 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 16.5.2015. 2:34:32 +02:00

'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

As I already stated, I executed each request in its own context like so:

```
        using (var context = new MockContext())
        {
            // Test overrided behaviour 
            // This should return just deleted entity
            // Enable soft-delete retrieval
            context.ShouldFetchSoftDeleted = true;

            // Request 1 goes here
            // context.Items.Where(...).ToList()
        }

        using (var context = new MockContext())
        {
            // Request 2 goes here
            // context.Items.Where(...).ToList()
        }
```

Comment: Are you saving the changes to the Database or your changes are made locally? Your code does not expose that.
If your issue is that you are not retrieving the updated data form the database, you can try retrieving the data from the DB. The "GetDatabaseValues" is used for retrieving updated data and not the cached objects:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.getdatabasevalues%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Evaluate using expresion trees. The compilation will be on the fly but will impact performance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: Instead of doing so much, why wouldn't you simply override SaveChanges and before deleting entity, you can update softdelete column.

Comment: @AkashKava I'm doing that. But what about retrieving entities? I would then need to change every repository to filter deleted objects and to be honest, we're not doing all operations through repositories - that's why we planned to implement this using interceptor (as many of developers suggested this would work).

Comment: I have added Query<T> as an answer.

Comment: I think I am having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution @AleksandarToplek?

Comment: @jinavar1 Have you find a workaround?

Comment: @jannagy02 We gave up on EF handling soft delete and refactored our code implementing repository layer with exact functionality.

Comment: We gave up, too.

Answer (score 9):

It's important to distinguish between **Query Plan Caching** and **Result Caching**:

**[Caching in the Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3)**

**Query Plan Caching**

> The first time a query is executed, it goes through the internal plan compiler to translate the conceptual query into the store command (e.g. the T-SQL which is executed when run against SQL Server).  If query plan caching is enabled, the next time the query is executed the store command is retrieved directly from the query plan cache for execution, bypassing the plan compiler.
>
> The query plan cache is shared across ObjectContext instances within
>   the same AppDomain. You don't need to hold onto an ObjectContext
>   instance to benefit from query plan caching.

A Query Cache is an optimized SQL instruction plan. These plans help make EF queries faster than "Cold" Queries. These Plans are cached beyond and particular context.

**Object caching:**

> By default when an entity is returned in the results of a query, just
>   before EF materializes it, the ObjectContext will check if an entity
>   with the same key has already been loaded into its ObjectStateManager.
>   If an entity with the same keys is already present EF will include it
>   in the results of the query. Although EF will still issue the query
>   against the database, this behavior can bypass much of the cost of
>   materializing the entity multiple times.

In other words, Object Caching is a soft form of Results Caching. No other kind 2nd Level Cache is available with Entity Framework unless you specifically include it. [Second-Level Caching in the Entity Framework and Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx)

**[AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)**

> Returns a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in
>   the DbContext or ObjectContext

```
Context.Set<Objects>().AsNoTracking();
```

Or you can disable object caching for an entity using [MergeOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.mergeoption(v=vs.113).aspx)  `NoTracking` Option:

> Will not modify cache.

```
context.Objects.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; 
var retrievedObj= context.Objects.Find(obj.Id);
```

As opposed to the `AppendOnly` Option

> Will only append new (top level-unique) rows. This is the default behavior.

this is the default behavior you have been struggling with

Comment: I have not tried your implementation, but the problem is not object caching, its the query caching that causes this. I use new context for each request so object caching can't happen. But query is not recompiled when I want it to.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek, Query caching is cimpoling the query instructions. An Object Cache is for the specific data pertaining to query against an object.

Comment: when I first retrieve objects w/o softdelete flag, i receive `null` (there is 1 object in db that is softdeleted), second call with softdelete disabled - result is still `null`. Can this still be Object Caching? I do inject custom parameters into query with QueryVisitor depending of softdelete flag. If the softdelete flag is set to `true` i inject, into normal find query, filter that only returns object with `IsDeleted == true`. This query gets cached, and then when I disable softdelete flag, query gets retrieved from cache and reused (with that filter) instead of recompiled.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek, I think it is. Object Cache is basically keeping track of which rows should be included. If you check my answer, the default is an "Append" mode. The problem with a "Soft delete", is it conflicts with a "soft cache" that waits for delete instructions to remove from cache.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek, to find out I suggest you simply turn off object caching, re-run your app and find out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you problem happens in all queries? In your example you have used the Find(), what if you use ToList()? The problem doesn't happen, right?

For testing purposes, try using Where method instead of Find(), I believe that you won't have problems...

If the above theory is true, replace the Find() by Where inside a some kind of repository class. Then you don't need to change anything else in your code.

For example, in your repository class:

```
public YourClass Find(id)
{
    //do not use Find here 
    return context.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id); //or Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

In your business logic:

```
var user = repository.Find(id);
```

---

The Find() method documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.113%29.aspx says:

"...if an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store..."

So, I believe that the problem is the Find(). Using a repository pattern, replacing Find by Where, is the easiest workaround that I can imagine right now. Or else, instead of replace, you can check if the softdelete is activated, and then choose your preferred method. What do you think about that?

A more difficult approach is creating a class that inherits from DbSet and override the Find(), which will be too complicated.

**EDIT**

To help us see what is happening, create a console application and log the database operation, like this:

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    // Your code here... 
    // Call your query twice, with and without softdelete
}
```

Paste the log, then we'll see for sure if the sql is incorrect or the data is being cached.

**EDIT 2**

Ok... instead of adding the interceptor in the constructor of the configuration class, add it in the constructor of the context, like this:

```
//the dbcontext class      

 private IDbCommandTreeInterceptor softDeleteInterceptor;
 public DataContext()
       : base("YourConnection")
 {
    //add the interceptor 
    softDeleteInterceptor = new SoftDeleteInterceptor()           
      DbInterception.Add(softDeleteInterceptor);
 }
```

Then, inside your context class, create a method that removes the interceptor, like this:

```
public void DisableSoftDelete() 
{
     DbInterception.Remove(softDeleteInterceptor);
}
```

Call the method above when you want to disable the softdelete, `context.DisableSoftDelete();`

Comment: I'm using new context for each request so that shouldn't be the problem. I'll check if this is the case in a bit and let you know.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not matter whether I use Find, Where or First*. I placed breakpoint in TreeCreated method and second time it does not get called. I want it to be called every time.

Comment: To help us to see what is really happening

Comment: Take a look at **Edit 2**

Comment: Take a look at my **Edit 2**

Comment: I'll take a look today. But won't that still cache query when softdelete is disabled and then use that same query when i re-enable softdelete?

Comment: I don't believe so, I've been reading the docs, the query shouldn't be chached... I think that, somehow, the interceptor is being "cached", so removing it will force EF to generate the query again

Comment: Just figured these guys had same problem but named it differently. https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters/issues/8

Comment: I'll take a look... So, removing the interceptor before the new query didn't work for you?

Comment: Didn't really try it out as I'm not in office right now, but first thing in the morning.

Comment: I gave you bounty points so that it doesn't get awarded randomly. Your solution doesn't really work. But hey, better give you - spent most time helping.

Comment: Thank you very much! But don't give up. I'll try to simulate you problem step by step in this weekend. I'll contact you if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To update softdelete, you can override SaveChanges method, and to create filter, you can use `dbContext.Query<T>()` which will apply soft delete filter automatically using expression generator.

To filter your soft delete column, you can implement following method, in your DbContext.

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>(){

   var ds = this.Set<T>() as IQueryable<T>;

   var entityType = typeof(T);

   if(!softDeleteSupported)
        return ds;

   ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
   Expression compare = Expression.Equals( 
          Expression.Property(pe, "SoftDeleted"),
          Expression.Constant(false));

   Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter = 
       Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(compare,pe);

   return ds.Where(filter);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require all data calls to call Query?

Comment: Yes it would, but it is eventually free from EF implementation.

Comment: This is not what I want. There are many ways to implement softdelete, but I have application in production and can't rewrite all requests - that is the reason we went with interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked some time ago, but since no post was marked as answer i share my recent experiences with that issue. As Dave correctly explained "It's important to distinguish between Query Plan Caching and Result Caching". Here the problem is Query Plan Caching, because

> A Query Cache is an optimized SQL instruction plan. These plans help make EF queries faster than "Cold" Queries. **These Plans are cached beyond and particular context.**

So even if you create a new context, the problem remains, because the interceptor is not applied to "Query Plan cached" queries. My solution to this is very simple. Instead of relying only on the Interceptor, we can add a Where clause to the query in case of ShouldFetchSoftDeleted = true. With that EF uses another query and does not reuse the wrongly cached one. The interceptor now will be called but ShouldFetchSoftDeleted = true prevents your QueryVisitor to apply the IsDeleted filter.

I'm using a Repository pattern, but I think the concept is clear.

```
public override IQueryable<TEntity> Find<TEntity>()
{
   var query = GetRepository<TEntity>().Find();

   if (!ShouldFetchSoftDeleted)
   {
     return query; // interceptor handles soft delete
   }

   query = GetRepository<TEntity>().Find();
   return Where<IDeletedInfo, TEntity>(query, x => x.IsDeleted == false || x.IsDeleted);
}
```