# How would i force EF to create new query commands every time or Or how would I go about implementing an interceptor to achieve row level restrictions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, interceptor

[Why is IDbCommandTreeInterceptor being skipped on second query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650065/why-is-idbcommandtreeinterceptor-being-skipped-on-second-query/46650920#46650920)

Answered here, query command trees are cached by model which means that command tree creation only happens the first time a query is executed. So how would I force EF to create new query commands, or if that is not possible how would I go about implementing an interceptor to achieve row level restrictions on the application level.

Comment: Could you use a `DbCommandInterceptor` and override `NonQueryExecuting` to do the work you wanted to do there?

Comment: What's a "row level restriction" in this case? Permission for a user to see or not see a whole row based on access checks, or something more complicated involving columns? [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30173913/4137916). Frankly, this would motivate me to consider moving the restriction to the database itself ([which is viable from SQL Server 2016 onwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security)). Although, realistically, I wouldn't be using EF in the first place so there's little trouble adding it to my DB layer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you put that as an answer so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` use a class derived from `DbCommandInterceptor` and override `NonQueryExecuting` to do the work you wanted to do there.